# JavaFX Login access denied

Tags: java, javafx

When I try to login with redbull as username and pass123 as password it doesnt show the access granted message instead goes to else statement and show the access denied message

```
    Label usernameLb = new Label("Username:");
    GridPane.setConstraints(usernameLb, 0, 0);

    TextField usernameTf = new TextField();
    usernameTf.setPromptText("Username");
    GridPane.setConstraints(usernameTf , 1, 0);

    Label passLb = new Label("Password:");
    GridPane.setConstraints(passLb, 0, 1);

    TextField passTf = new TextField();
    passTf.setPromptText("Password");
    GridPane.setConstraints(passTf, 1, 1);

    Button loginBtn = new Button("Login");
    loginBtn.setOnAction(e -> {

        String username = usernameTf.getText();
        String password = passTf.getText();

        if (username == "redbull" && password == "pass123"){

            System.out.println(username + "\n" + password);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, 
                    "Access Granted", " ", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);

        } else {

            System.out.println(username + "\n" + password);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, 
                    "Access Denied", " ", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
        }
    });

    GridPane.setConstraints(loginBtn, 1, 2);

    gridPane.getChildren().addAll(usernameLb, 
    usernameTf, passLb, passTf, loginBtn);

    Scene scene1 = new Scene(gridPane, 300, 200);
    window.setScene(scene1);
    window.show();

}
```

Comment: You cannot reliably compare strings using `==`. Use `if(username.equals("redbull")` instead...

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Use `.equals()` when comparing the value of two Strings.

`(username.equals("redbull") && password.equals("pass123"))`

Comment: [How should duplicate questions be handled?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10844)